# How to upload on http server part of file using POST or PUT? Can I use described solution?

Tags: android, http, upload, httpclient, put

I have a task. Upload on http server part of a file (I must skip beginning of the file).

How can I do it. Do you know good solution?

Can I use my own solution? Is it safe?

My solution. I made subclass of FileEntity that gives file stream and skips beginning of the file.

1. I put my entity to request.

   HttpPut request = new HttpPut(this.uri);

   request.setEntity(new FileOfsetEntity(new File(getDestination()), "binary/octet-stream", ofset));
2. My FileOfsetEntity skips begining of the file.

   ```
   class FileOfsetEntity extends FileEntity {

   long ofset = 0;
   public FileOfsetEntity(File file, String contentType, long ofset) {
     super(file, contentType);
     this.ofset = ofset;
   }
   @Override
   public long getContentLength() {
     return this.file.length() - ofset;
   }
   @Override
   public InputStream getContent() throws IOException {
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(this.file);
     long skiped = in.skip(ofset);
     Log.w("FileOfsetEntity.getContent","skiped = " + skiped);
     return in;
   }
   @Override
   public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
     if (outstream == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Output stream may not be null");
     }
     InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(this.file);
     long skiped = instream.skip(ofset);
     Log.w("FileOfsetEntity.writeTo","skiped = " + skiped);
     try {
         byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
         int l;
         long readed = skiped;
         while ((l = instream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
             readed += l;
             outstream.write(tmp, 0, l);
             Log.v("FileOfsetEntity.writeTo",file.getAbsolutePath() + " readed = " + readed + " skiped = " + skiped);
         }
         outstream.flush();
     } finally {
         instream.close();
     } }}
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this may fail or go through.

I would suggest, a different way of doing this. I presume that you know the office before uploading.

Here is a [link to upload file](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/) to server.

In this code, move your offset and then start writing it into the stream.